# How to execute javascript code on IFrame load

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically creating an iframe with javascript inside the body.

```
iframe = m_oYDOM.get("ifAdwords");

iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = &lt;script type=\"text/javascript\"&gt;function Test(){alert(\"Success\");Test();}&lt;/script>";
```

I am not able to get the alert to work. Can someone help me!

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page

Comment: The above link is about calling a function from the parent page. But I want the function to be executed on iframe load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working

```
iframe = document.getElementByID("iFrameID");
var oDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
oDoc.open();
oDoc.write('<html><body><script type=\"text/javascript\">function Test(){alert(\"success\");}Test();<\/script><\/body><\/html>');
oDoc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

.innerHTML is only for text changes... Call the script from another *.html file. OR just add onload to the end of iframe like so:

```
<iframe src="test.html" onload="alert('Success')";>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example using jQuery that I use to execute javascript when a frame has loaded, I use it when redirecting the user to download a zip file, to control the browser after the download dialog appears.

Add a div to the page that will hold the iframe:

```
    <div style='height: 1px; width: 1px; border: 0;' id='iframediv'></div>
```

Then call the following to create the iframe with the onload action:

```
     var url = "http://google.com"
     $('#iframediv').html('<IFRAME id="downloadAlbum" onload="loadFunction()" src="'+url+'"></iframe>');
```

Change url and loadFunction as required.